# How to find closest form inbetween td

Tags: jquery

I have an odd situation. I need to have a form inbetween `td`s. I need this for some inrow updates that are ajax and only wish to submit a row in sections. So each row may have 2 or three forms.

However, `$(this).closest` does not find this `form` -> `undefined`.
How best can I select this `form`?

My **html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form myid='hi'>
        <td> <a href="#">Delete</a> </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form myid='hi2'>
        <td> <a href="#">Delete</a> </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My **jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).closest('form').attr('myid');  
    alert(val);  // undefined!
    return false; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbc4G/3/

Comment: "inbetween tds"!!!! Don't do it!!! That's totally invalid HTML.

Comment: Turn the form/td inside out as follows: `<td><form myid='hi'><a href="#">Delete</a></form></td>`. That's valid and makes the jQuery selector trivial.

Comment: Even better, get rid of the forms altogether. I suspect they are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/NGJKK/)***

Go up to the closest `td`, and then find the first previous form

```
var val = $(this).parents('td:first').prev("form:first").attr('myid');   
alert(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make my html invalid by:-

1. Placing form as child of `tr`
2. Having custom attribute not prefixed by `data-`

Not sure your exact HTML layout but you could try this way instead.

#### Html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form data-myid='hi'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
                        <td>Label</td>
                        <td> <a href="#">Delete</a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <form data-myid='hi1'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
                        <td>Label</td>
                        <td> <a href="#">Delete</a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <form data-myid='hi2'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
                        <td>Label</td>
                        <td> <a href="#">Delete</a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Script:-

```
$('a').click(function () {

    var val = $(this).closest('form').data('myid');
    alert(val);
    return false;
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2yVx/)

Comment: yeah dont make your html invalid, now you may hack it by using selectors tomorrow that might stop working. And try to do the right way to avoid any unexpected issues,

Comment: Why all this nested tables? Use CSS for layout, with all chance not even the original forms are needed at all, because the `myid` attribute can be tied to the closest `<tr>` itself.

Comment: @moonwave99 Of course its just an example based on ops samplr. But my point is in my answer.